# Geofence: Uncaught (in promise): Class not found

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic4, ionic-native

### Initialize Geofence throw uncaught error "class not found"

Already tried:

1. Removing/Adding Android platform
2. Using After Platform is ready
3. Installed Google play service on device and emulator
4. Liveload working specified error but build android not working after installing cordova-plugin-geofence

***I got this message while installing***

```
PS C:\Users\one solution\mrca> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geofence
    > cordova.cmd plugin add cordova-plugin-geofence
    Installing "cordova-plugin-geofence" for android
    Installing "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support" for android
    Android Studio project detected
    **Installing "cordova-plugin-compat" for android
    Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 7.1.4, failed version requirement:
          <6.3.0
    Skipping 'cordova-plugin-compat' for android**
    Installing "es6-promise-plugin" for android
    Subproject Path: CordovaLib
    Subproject Path: app
    Adding cordova-plugin-geofence to package.json
```

Ionic:

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.5 (C:\Users\onesolution\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.6.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 17 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.6.0 (update available: 0.8.0)
   native-run  : 0.2.8

System:

   NodeJS : v10.16.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.9.0
   OS     : Windows 10
```

***home.page.ts***

```
 constructor(private geofence: Geofence) {
         geofence.initialize().then(
           // resolved promise does not return a value
           () => console.log('Geofence Plugin Ready'), //<-- Expected
           (err) => console.log(err)  //<- Class not found
         ) }
```

**Error Occured**

```
core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Class not found
        at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
        at zone.js:741
        at geofence.js:143
        at Object.callbackFromNative (cordova.js:293)
        at processMessage (cordova.js:1115)
        at processMessages (cordova.js:1138)
        at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
        at Object.onInvoke (core.js:17299)
        at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)
        at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:150)
```

Repo bitbucket
**git clone https://umesh0510@bitbucket.org/umesh0510/geofence-test.git**

**Expected: Geofence Plugin Ready**

Answer (score 1):

I was facing `Class Not Found` error in my app Ionic4 incase of app-version plugin because I was testing my app with livereload functionality. We should **build the app again whenever new plugin is installed in the app especially when livereload is in progress**